# Grouping repetitions in an array?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, repeat

I am looking for a function that gets a one dimensional sorted array and returns
a two dimensional array with two columns, first column containing non-repeated 
items and second column containing number of repetiotions of the item. Right now
my code is as follows:

```
def priorsGrouper(priors):
    if priors.size==0:
        ret=priors;
    elif priors.size==1:
        ret=priors[0],1;
    else:
        ret=numpy.zeros((1,2));
        pointer1,pointer2=0,0;
        while(pointer1<priors.size):
            counter=0;
            while(pointer2<priors.size and priors[pointer2]==priors[pointer1]):
                counter+=1;
                pointer2+=1;
            ret=numpy.row_stack((ret,[priors[pointer1],pointer2-pointer1]))
            pointer1=pointer2;
    return ret;
print priorsGrouper(numpy.array([1,2,2,3]))
```

My output is as follows:

```
[[ 0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.]
 [ 2.  2.]
 [ 3.  1.]]
```

First of all I cannot get rid of my [0,0]. Secondly I want to know if there is
a numpy or scipy function for this or is mine OK?

Thanks.

Comment: If the first column of the result array has "non repeated items", how can the second column have "number of repetitions of the item"?

Comment: I want the output to be structured like that. I'll add an example.

Comment: Right. Sorry searched but was not able to find it. Do I have to delete this one?

Comment: No, not at all. It's just a way of saying "Your answer may already be over here." Even closed duplicates can be helpful because they point back to the original.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [np.unique](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) to get the unique values in `x`, as well as an array of indices (called `inverse`). The `inverse` can be thought of as "labels" for the elements in `x`. Unlike `x` itself, the labels are always integers, starting at 0.

Then you can take a [bincount](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) of the labels. Since the labels start at 0, the bincount won't be filled with a lot of zeros that you don't care about.

Finally, [column_stack](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html) will join `y` and the bincount into a 2D array:

```
In [84]: x = np.array([1,2,2,3])

In [85]: y, inverse = np.unique(x, return_inverse=True)

In [86]: y
Out[86]: array([1, 2, 3])

In [87]: inverse
Out[87]: array([0, 1, 1, 2])

In [88]: np.bincount(inverse)
Out[88]: array([1, 2, 1])

In [89]: np.column_stack((y,np.bincount(inverse)))
Out[89]: 
array([[1, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [3, 1]])
```

---

Sometimes when an array is small, it turns out that using plain Python methods are faster than NumPy functions. I wanted to check if that was the case here, and, if so, how large `x` would have to be before NumPy methods are faster.

Here is a graph of the performance of various methods as a function of the size of `x`:
[image]

```
In [173]: x = np.random.random(1000)

In [174]: x.sort()

In [156]: %timeit using_unique(x)
10000 loops, best of 3: 99.7 us per loop

In [180]: %timeit using_groupby(x)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.64 ms per loop

In [157]: %timeit using_counter(x)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.31 ms per loop

In [158]: %timeit using_ordered_dict(x)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.7 ms per loop
```

For `len(x)` of 1000, `using_unique` is over 35x faster than any of the plain Python methods tested.

So it looks like `using_unique` is fastest, even for very small `len(x)`.

---

Here is the program used to generate the graph:

```
import numpy as np
import collections
import itertools as IT
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import timeit

def using_unique(x):
    y, inverse = np.unique(x, return_inverse=True)
    return np.column_stack((y, np.bincount(inverse)))

def using_counter(x):
    result = collections.Counter(x)
    return np.array(sorted(result.items()))

def using_ordered_dict(x):
    result = collections.OrderedDict()
    for item in x:
        result[item] = result.get(item,0)+1
    return np.array(result.items())

def using_groupby(x):
    return np.array([(k, sum(1 for i in g)) for k, g in IT.groupby(x)])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
timing = collections.defaultdict(list)
Ns = [int(round(n)) for n in np.logspace(0, 3, 10)]
for n in Ns:
    x = np.random.random(n)
    x.sort()
    timing['unique'].append(
        timeit.timeit('m.using_unique(m.x)', 'import __main__ as m', number=1000))
    timing['counter'].append(
        timeit.timeit('m.using_counter(m.x)', 'import __main__ as m', number=1000))
    timing['ordered_dict'].append(
        timeit.timeit('m.using_ordered_dict(m.x)', 'import __main__ as m', number=1000))
    timing['groupby'].append(
        timeit.timeit('m.using_groupby(m.x)', 'import __main__ as m', number=1000))

ax.plot(Ns, timing['unique'], label='using_unique')
ax.plot(Ns, timing['counter'], label='using_counter')
ax.plot(Ns, timing['ordered_dict'], label='using_ordered_dict')
ax.plot(Ns, timing['groupby'], label='using_groupby')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.ylabel('milliseconds')
plt.xlabel('size of x')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

If order is not important, use Counter.

```
from collections import Counter
% Counter([1,2,2,3])
= Counter({2: 2, 1: 1, 3: 1})
% Counter([1,2,2,3]).items()
[(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 1)]
```

To preserve order (by first appearance), you can implement your own version of Counter:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
def OrderedCounter(seq):
     res = OrderedDict()
     for x in seq:
        res.setdefault(x, 0) 
        res[x] += 1
     return res
% OrderedCounter([1,2,2,3])
= OrderedDict([(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 1)])
% OrderedCounter([1,2,2,3]).items()
= [(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 1)]
```

Comment: It makes an unsorted output!

Comment: Right. do you want it to be sorted by order of first appearance?

Comment: Yes, and I think sorting the output would be an overhead!

Comment: I edited my answer to include a solution for that (not involving sorting of course)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count repetitions of an item you can use a dictionary:

```
l = [1, 2, 2, 3]
d = {}
for i in l:
    if i not in d:
        d[i] = 1
    else:
        d[i] += 1
result = [[k, v] for k, v in d.items()]
```

For your example returns:

```
[[1, 1],
 [2, 2], 
 [3, 1]]
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need to end your statements with semicolons (`;`), this isn't C.  :-)

Second, line 5 (and others) set `ret` to be `value,value` but that isn't a list:

```
>type foo.py
def foo():
        return [1],2
a,b = foo()
print "a = {0}".format(a)
print "b = {0}".format(b)
```

Gives:

```
>python foo.py
a = [1]
b = 2
```

Third: there are easier ways to do this, here's what comes to mind:

- Use the Set constructor to create a unique list of items
- Create a list of the number of times each entry in Set occurs in the input string
- Use zip() to combine and return the two lists as set of tuples (although this isn't exactly what you were asking for)

Here's one way:

```
def priorsGrouper(priors):
    """Find out how many times each element occurs in a list.

    @param[in] priors List of elements
    @return Two-dimensional list: first row is the unique elements,
                second row is the number of occurrences of each element.
    """

    # Generate a `list' containing only unique elements from the input
    mySet = set(priors)

    # Create the list that will store the number of occurrences
    occurrenceCounts = []

    # Count how many times each element occurs on the input:
    for element in mySet:
        occurrenceCounts.append(priors.count(element))

    # Combine the two:
    combinedArray = zip(mySet, occurrenceCounts)
# End of priorsGrouper() ----------------------------------------------

# Check zero-element case
print priorsGrouper([])

# Check multi-element case
sampleInput = ['a','a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c']
print priorsGrouper(sampleInput)
```